# Connect to Putty Using VPN

Tags: vpn, putty, pptp

When I try to connect Putty using Virtual Private Network (p p tp), I am getting this error:

```
Server Unexpectedly closed (window).
```

I got the specified IP address shell, and it asked me to enter the username and password, then after I gave the credentials, there was a long delay, and finally I got the above error.

At times I am getting the error *before* entering the password too.

[image: popup error message]

Answer (score 0):

this is due to Dynamic host so i reserved single ipaddress

Comment: If you have resolved the problem, please mark your answer as "accepted" by clicking the gray check mark next to it. That way other people will know you're all set. Thanks and welcome to AskUbuntu!